# Как подвязать данные к элементам combobox

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qcombobox

Имеется список `wk_list` полученный от сервера по `ssh`. В `combobox` выводится первое значение **`pc1`**, **`pc2`**, **`pc3`** и т.д.

Как можно подключаться к **`pc1`** по **`ip 10.20.35.25`**, **`pc2`** по **`ip 10.20.35.26`** и т.д используя combobox без отдельной кнопки подключения?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.rows = [
            ('10.16.26.25', 2),
            ('10.16.26.26', 3),
            ('10.16.26.27', 1),
            ('10.16.26.28', 4)
        ]
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText='Введите номер из 4х цифр')
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.func_connect)  #прикрутим Enter после ввода в lineedit

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('SCAN')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)

        #Combobox
        self.cmbState = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
##        self.cmbState.currentTextChanged.connect(self.WK_VNC)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['IP', 'Number', 'SSH', 'VNC'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cmbState) #add combobox

    def func_connect(self):
        num = self.lineEdit.text()

        #список для добавления в combobox
        wk_list = [['pc1', '10.20.35.25'], ['pc2', '10.20.35.26'], ['pc3', '10.20.35.27']]
        self.cmbState.clear()
        for w in wk_list:
            wk_list = (w[0])
            wk_lis_ip = (w[1])
            self.cmbState.addItem(wk_list)
        self.cmbState.currentTextChanged.connect(lambda self: print(wk_list_ip))

        if not num.isdigit():
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage(
                'Достустимо вводить только цифры, номер состоит из 4х цифр')
            return
        if len(num) != 4 :
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('Номер состоит из 4х цифр, повторите ввод.')
            return
        self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('')

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.rows))
        for row, items in enumerate(self.rows):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'SSH {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_SSH(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, button)

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'VNC {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 3, button)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        index = self.parent.tabWidget.currentIndex()        #
        self.parent.tabWidget.setTabText(index, num)        #


    def button_pushed_SSH(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

    def button_pushed_VNC(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

##    def WK_VNC(self, txt):
##        print(self, {}.format(txt))

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Добавить", autoRaise=True)
        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QtWidgets.QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(
            count, QtWidgets.QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)

        self.new_tab()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_tab)

    def new_tab(self):
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 0
        tabPage = MyTab(self)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, tabPage, f"Tab {index}")
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        tabPage.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def close_tab(self, index):
        if self.tabWidget.count() > 2:
            self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 11, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(680, 480)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: получилось подключиться с помощью lambda функции, но подключается всегда только к одному ip . Наверное в lambda нужно реализовывать цикл, но я пока не пойму как
```self.cmbState.currentTextChanged.connect(lambda self: print(wk_list_ip))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **currentData** : const QVariant
>
> Это свойство содержит данные для текущего элемента.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.rows = [
            ('10.16.26.25', 2),
            ('10.16.26.26', 3),
            ('10.16.26.27', 1),
            ('10.16.26.28', 4)
        ]
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText='Введите номер из 4х цифр')
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.func_connect)  #прикрутим Enter после ввода в lineedit

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('SCAN')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)

        #Combobox
        self.cmbState = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
         
        self.cmbState.currentTextChanged.connect(self.WK_VNC)     # +++ 

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['IP', 'Number', 'SSH', 'VNC'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cmbState) #add combobox

    def func_connect(self):
        num = self.lineEdit.text()

        #список для добавления в combobox
        
        wk_list = [
            ['pc1', '10.20.35.25'], 
            ['pc2', '10.20.35.26'], 
            ['pc3', '10.20.35.27']
        ]

        self.cmbState.clear()
        for w in wk_list:
##            wk_list = (w[0])
##            self.cmbState.addItem(wk_list)
            self.cmbState.addItem(* w)                      # +++ 

        if not num.isdigit():
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage(
                'Достустимо вводить только цифры, номер состоит из 4х цифр')
            return
        if len(num) != 4 :
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('Номер состоит из 4х цифр, повторите ввод.')
            return
        self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('')

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.rows))
        for row, items in enumerate(self.rows):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'SSH {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_SSH(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, button)

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'VNC {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 3, button)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        index = self.parent.tabWidget.currentIndex()        #
        self.parent.tabWidget.setTabText(index, num)        #


    def button_pushed_SSH(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

    def button_pushed_VNC(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

    def WK_VNC(self, txt):
#        print(self, {}.format(txt))
        print(f'данные для текущего элемента {txt} --> {self.cmbState.currentData()}')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Добавить", autoRaise=True)
        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QtWidgets.QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(
            count, QtWidgets.QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)

        self.new_tab()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_tab)

    def new_tab(self):
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 0
        tabPage = MyTab(self)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, tabPage, f"Tab {index}")
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        tabPage.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def close_tab(self, index):
        if self.tabWidget.count() > 2:
            self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 11, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(680, 480)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Но при нажатии `SCAN` сразу происходит подключение к одному из pc. Можно ли поставить или добавить заглушку? Или тут без отдельной кнопки подключения не обойтись?

Можно, например так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.rows = [
            ('10.16.26.25', 2),
            ('10.16.26.26', 3),
            ('10.16.26.27', 1),
            ('10.16.26.28', 4)
        ]
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            placeholderText='Введите номер из 4х цифр')
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.func_connect)  #прикрутим Enter после ввода в lineedit

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('SCAN')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)

        #Combobox
        self.cmbState = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
         
        self.cmbState.currentTextChanged.connect(self.WK_VNC)     # +++ 

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['IP', 'Number', 'SSH', 'VNC'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cmbState) #add combobox

    def func_connect(self):
        num = self.lineEdit.text()

        #список для добавления в combobox
        
        wk_list = [
            ['Выберите pc1 для подключения'],
            ['pc1', '10.20.35.25'], 
            ['pc2', '10.20.35.26'], 
            ['pc3', '10.20.35.27']
        ]

        self.cmbState.clear()
        for w in wk_list:
##            wk_list = (w[0])
##            self.cmbState.addItem(wk_list)
            self.cmbState.addItem(* w)                      # +++ 

        if not num.isdigit():
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage(
                'Достустимо вводить только цифры, номер состоит из 4х цифр')
            return
        if len(num) != 4 :
            self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('Номер состоит из 4х цифр, повторите ввод.')
            return
        self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('')

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.rows))
        for row, items in enumerate(self.rows):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'SSH {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_SSH(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, button)

            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'VNC {row}')
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 3, button)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        index = self.parent.tabWidget.currentIndex()        #
        self.parent.tabWidget.setTabText(index, num)        #


    def button_pushed_SSH(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

    def button_pushed_VNC(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}, lineEdit={self.lineEdit.text()}')

    def WK_VNC(self, txt):
        currentData = self.cmbState.currentData()
        if currentData:
            print(f'данные для текущего элемента {txt} --> {currentData}')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Добавить", autoRaise=True)
        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.new_tab)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QtWidgets.QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(
            count, QtWidgets.QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)

        self.new_tab()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_tab)

    def new_tab(self):
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 0
        tabPage = MyTab(self)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, tabPage, f"Tab {index}")
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        tabPage.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def close_tab(self, index):
        if self.tabWidget.count() > 2:
            self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 11, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(680, 480)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: спасибо все работает! Но при нажатии SCAN сразу происходит подключение к одному из pc. Можно ли поставить или добавить заглушку? Или тут без отдельной кнопки подключения не обойтись?

Comment: @elchako я добавил обновление в ответ

Comment: Еще раз спасибо! Твои советы очень ценны. Это то что нужно